# Can we print Marathi language text using esc_pos_printer: ^4.1.0 in Flutter

Tags: flutter, thermal-printer, escpos

In my project i want to print the text in Marathi Language is it possible.
Here is my code

```
Future<void> printMarathiText() async {
    final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final printer = NetworkPrinter(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
    List<int> bytes = [];
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
    await connectToPrinter();

    bytes += generator.text('मराठी मध्ये टेक्स्ट प्रिंट करणारा प्रिंटर',
        styles: const PosStyles(
          align: PosAlign.center,
          height: PosTextSize.size1,
          width: PosTextSize.size1,
        ),
        linesAfter: 1);

    printer.cut();
    printer.disconnect();
  }
```

I am getting error as

```
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (string): Contains invalid characters.: "मराठी मध्ये टेक्   स्ट प्रिंट करणारा प्रिंटर"
```

is there any solution for this?

Comment: Doesn't it depend on the vendor and model information of the printer you are using? It may not be supported at the moment. [esc_pos_utils/lib/resources/capabilities.json](https://github.com/andrey-ushakov/esc_pos_utils/blob/master/lib/resources/capabilities.json), [ESC t](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/ref_escpos_en/esc_lt.html), [Page 82 \[Marathi\]](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/charcode/ref_charcode_en/page_82.html), [FS ( C <Function 48>](https://download4.epson.biz/sec_pubs/pos/reference_en/escpos/ref_escpos_en/fs_lparen_cc_fn48.html)

Comment: @kunif Yes, it depends and but the printer I am using supports all the languages as I have checked printing through notepad, it works there.

Comment: The fact that you checked with notepad means that it is configured as a document printer on Windows? Isn't the confirmation method using notepad printed as a bit image instead of ESCPOS text? Please try the library after deleting the device from the Windows printer list and registering the information about the printer you are using in capabilities.json as introduced in the previous comment.

Comment: Actually I am trying to print on Thermal Printer for printing. I just tried checking on notepad that does it support other languages or not. Here's details about printer Name: Thermal Receipt Printer, Model: MP583, Interfaces: USB+BT . I am trying to print through Bluetooth from my flutter app.

Comment: Do you understand the standard mechanism of Windows document printers (create and print all content as BitImage or vector data)? And do you understand that many free software ESCPOS libraries do not use this mechanism, but instead send the text code of the characters directly to the printer and print in the printer's own font?

Comment: No, I am quite new to it.

Comment: It is probably this printer [Mobile printer MobiPrint MP- 583](https://www.eng.mobilator.pl/drukarka-mobilna-mobiprint-mp-583-produkt-86286.html), but it seems to only support ASCII and GBK (Chinese?) fonts. If you only support those two and want to print Marathi, you will need to create all the print content in BitImage like Windows document printers and request printing of that BitImage.

Comment: Hey @kunif, do you have any idea how I can achieve this in Flutter? I've tried a lot, but I'm still unable to print in BitImage or String.

Comment: I've never used flutter/dart/bluetoothprinter, so I don't know what to do. I am commenting with general knowledge about ESC/POS. If you search for these and image printing as keywords, you will find several articles, so why not try out the ones that seem useful?

Comment: I have tried everything from every source, but I still didn't get the proper solution.

Comment: For example, if you divide the stages into ASCII-TEXT, images that are not text, such as logos, and ASCII-TEXT into images, how far can you go? Or are you trying to see if you can print to a full-spec thermal receipt printer (for example, TM-T88) that is not mobile? By checking the operation little by little in this way, you will need to detect what the problem is and deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
Future<void> printMarathiText() async {
  final profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
  final printer = NetworkPrinter(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
  final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
  await connectToPrinter();

  // Encode Marathi text as UTF-8
  final marathiText = 'मराठी मध्ये टेक्स्ट प्रिंट करणारा प्रिंटर';
  final marathiBytes = utf8.encode(marathiText);

  // Use a suitable font that supports Marathi characters
  final font = PosFont.custom(
    codeTable: 'CP1252', // Use the code table that matches your font
    width: 2,
    height: 2,
  );

  // Print Marathi text
  generator.textCustom(
    marathiBytes,
    styles: const PosStyles(
      align: PosAlign.center,
      height: PosTextSize.size2,
      width: PosTextSize.size2,
    ),
    linesAfter: 1,
    customStyles: [font],
  );

  printer.cut();
  printer.disconnect();
}
```

Comment: Hey @الرحمن الرحیم I am getting 2 error here which are 1 Undefined name 'PosFont'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name. and 2. The method 'textCustom' isn't defined for the type 'Generator'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'textCustom'. I am using these packages esc_pos_printer: ^4.1.0
  blue_thermal_printer: ^1.2.3

Comment: Can you get the details of the packages and their versions for the code?